# Waypoints remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I am using waypoints.js to handle a single-page site with a highlighted navigation. If the viewport reaches the class "content" the navigation point gets the class "active". The script works fine so far. What I want to achieve is if the `.content` element leaves the viewport, the class `.active` should be removed from the navigation point (`.content-nav-point`).

```
$('.content').waypoint(function() {
    $( '.content-nav-point' ).toggleClass('active');
}, { offset: '0%' });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the trick for you. Passing the `direction` parameter enables you to work with your scrolling direction to add/remove the class.

`$('.content').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
      $( '.content-nav-point' ).addClass('active');
    }
    else {
      $( '.content-nav-point' ).removeClass('active');
    }
      $( '.content-nav-point' ).toggleClass('active');
  }, { 
    offset: '0%' 
  });`

However, your offset option I don't think will help you for checking if an element has left the viewport. You'll need to modify your function to use the Inview shortcut for Waypoints instead of offset. See more here: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/inview/